# How do I process 3 separate XSLT files from a single XML to a single output?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT file that works with an XML to process a HTML (currently using X-trans & Notepad++). What I want to do is split it into 3 files, The Header, the body and the footer.

So far I have tried to use xsl:import & xsl:include but whenever I try to process it says the file is not valid. I'm clearly missing something can anyone help?

Header XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en-GB">
        <body style="font-family:'Praxis Com Light'; color:#632423; width:100%; font-size:14px !important;">


            <xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable2</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable3</xsl:variable>

            <div>Header</div>

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Body XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en-GB">
        <body style="font-family:'Praxis Com Light'; color:#632423; width:100%; font-size:14px !important;">


            <xsl:include href="Header.xsl"/>

            <xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable2</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable3</xsl:variable>

            <table>Main XSL file</table>

            <xsl:include href="Footer.xsl"/>


        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Footer XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en-GB">
        <body style="font-family:'Praxis Com Light'; color:#632423; width:100%; font-size:14px !important;">


            <xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable2</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable3</xsl:variable>

            <p>Footer</p>


        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

[image: Diagram to help Illustrate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `xsl:include` or `xsl:import` as top level elements, i.e. as direct children of the `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` element. Therefore a possible approach is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="header>


            <xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable2</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable3</xsl:variable>

            <div>Header</div>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="Header.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="Footer.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en-GB">
        <body style="font-family:'Praxis Com Light'; color:#632423; width:100%; font-size:14px !important;">

            <xsl:call-template name="header"/>

            <xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable2</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable>variable3</xsl:variable>

            <table>Main XSL file</table>

            <xsl:call-template name="footer"/>


        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of using named template it might be better to use template matching and perhaps modes but that depends on the structure of the XML to be processed.

Comment: Don't forget to give `<xsl:variable>variable1</xsl:variable>` and friends `@name` attributes.